# Why won't the GWT designer for eclipse work with GXT 3 widgets?

Tags: eclipse, gxt, gwt-designer

I'm trying to work with GXT 3 widgets in the GWT designer, without success.

I successfully managed to use GXT 2.2 with the designer but when switched to GXT 3, it seems that resources and images are missing. this seems odd because there are no folders for resources and images in GXT 3. What's going on here?

I am using GXT 3.0 GPL and Eclipse Indigo 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GXT 3 is not compatible with the Google plugin For Eclipse, thus you won't be able to use the GWT Designer to manipulate GXT 3 widgets.

The Google plugin and GWT Designer are compatible only with GXT 2.2 and currently there are not active projects designated to provide support for GXT3, due to the GPE becoming an open-source. This is, in my opinion, a job for the sencha community.

Answer (score 3):

Check this related forum question: [GWT Designer suport for GXT 3.0?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?170585-GWT-Designer-suport-for-GXT-3.0)

IMHO - It is very easy for Sencha to make money tweaking code a little bit to produce a next release and charge users for upgrade. Creating complex UI designer plug in for Ecliple / netbeans is not an easy money.

Overall: They are greedy and short-sighted.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, GXT team do not consider to support GWT designer for GXT 3.0. Google GWT Designer team also do not have any intention to support GXT 3.0 .. WYSWYG editor is just illusion for GXT 3.0 .. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?170585-GWT-Designer-suport-for-GXT-3.0